# Does Bolt of Genius restore ALL of a Cleric's uses of Healing Word or just one?

Tags: dnd-4e, cleric, powers

Here's the scenario:

The Cleric uses all their uses of `Healing Word` for the encounter.  Then the Battle Captain Warlord uses`Bolt of Genius` (PHB 154) on the Cleric to allow them to use `Healing Word` again. How many uses of `Healing Word` does the Cleric regain? All of them? Or just one use?

`Bolt of Genius` reads:

> **Effect:** The target regains an encounter power he or she has already used

Answer (score 6):

**One of them**

Each Healing word is an encounter power. While it is possible to make the argument that:

> You can use this power twice per encounter, but only once per round. At 16th level, you can use this power three times per encounter.

Means that the encounter is only "half-way used," the intent is clear. Furthermore, as restoring all healing words would be incredibly imbalancing, even if there is an alternate case that is made by the players, the GM should allow one and only one use of the power to be restored.

Comment: I use separate power cards for each use - so I'd definitely only restore one use/card.

Answer (score 1):

**All of them**

As a GM, I would rule "one of them" but I can see a counter argument along the lines of:

> You can use this power twice per encounter, but only once per round. At 16th level, you can use this power three times per encounter.

means that the power is not expended until it is used 2 (or 3) times.

At which point:

> The target regains an encounter power he or she has already used

restores it to its unused state.

I don't like this argument, but rules lawyer wise, I'm not sure that I see a good counter claim.

Answer (score 1):

**None of them**,

Healing word has this note:

> **Special**:
>
> You can use this power twice per encounter, but only once per round. At 16th level, you can use this power three times per encounter.

That note is already allowing you to exceed the normal usage of an encounter power.  It is more specific than any general power allowing you to regain encounter power and therefore takes precedence.  You cannot obtain more than 2 (or 3) uses of the Healing Word power per encounter.